# How to check if in app update code is working

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-update

I have a live app on playstore and I want to use [in_app_update](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update/example) package in flutter to check for app updates and update the app on user's phone. I have the following code which runs the app update in the background and shows a spinner until the updates are done. Before publishing this new code, I want to be sure if it works. In other words, how can I test if

```
 InAppUpdate.performImmediateUpdate()
```

will work when there is an update?

Does anyone have an idea how can I be sure if this code works before publishing it to playstore?

```
import 'package:in_app_update/in_app_update.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  var _isLoading;
  var appUpdate;
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
      });
    await InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate().then((info) {
      print('Starting app updates'); 
       AppUpdateInfo _updateInfo = info;
      appUpdate = _updateInfo.updateAvailable;
      print('App update aye? ' + appUpdate.toString());
      if(appUpdate)
       InAppUpdate.performImmediateUpdate()
                            .catchError((e) => print(e.toString()));
     print('Finishing app updates'); 
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e.toString());
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    print('isloadign to false'); 
      setState(() {
        // Get image url
      _isLoading = false;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !(_isLoading)?MultiProvider(
      providers: [
       ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Auth(),
        ),
        child: Consumer<Auth>(builder: (ctx, auth, _) => 
          MaterialApp(     
        title: 'MyApp', 
       home: ProductDetailScreen(),
        routes: {
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName:(ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
        }
      ),
        ) 
    ):Center(child:Loading());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try launching a release in `closed testing track` feature on Google Play. So it will be signed & published to Google Play but will be available only to chosen users. You can create a user, add yourself to the closed testing track.

As for the other point of view - This plugin wraps the official Android API, hence I recommend reading Android documentation to check if there is some information about testing it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I approach such kind of a problem is,

- Making the version in your `pubspec.yaml` file lower than the one you have on `Playstore` or `AppStore`. That way, the app detects that there is a published update and tries to run the update functionality from your build app.

Say, if on `PlayStore` or `AppStore` your app version is `1.0.0`, then in your `pubspec.yaml` file you will revert to anything lower than`1.0.0` like `0.0.7`.
And Voila!